# How to append to a slice whose element type is not a named type in golang

Tags: go, struct

I have two structs:

```
type ResponseQueryHotel struct {
    QueryString *string `json:"queryString"`
    Status   string `json:"status"`
    Action   string `json:"action"`
    RefCode  string `json:"refCode"`
    Vendorid string `json:"vendorid"`
    SearchToken *string `json:"searchtoken"`
    Data     struct {
        Hotels []struct {
            Data ResponseQueryHotelsData `json:"data"`
        } `json:"hotels"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

type ResponseQueryHotelsData struct {
    Hotelidvendor      string `json:"hotelidvendor"`
    Hotelname          string `json:"hotelname"`
    Hoteladdress       string `json:"hoteladdress"`
    Hoteldistrict      string `json:"hoteldistrict"`
    Hotelcity          string `json:"hotelcity"`
    Hotelprovince      string `json:"hotelprovince"`
    Hotelcountry       string `json:"hotelcountry"`
    Hotellat           string `json:"hotellat"`
    Hotellng           string `json:"hotellng"`
    Hotelprice         string `json:"hotelprice"`
    Hoteldiscountprice string `json:"hoteldiscountprice"`
    Hotelphotourl      string `json:"hotelphotourl"`
}
```

Now I need to append items to `ResponseQueryHotel.Data.Hotels`, whose element type is not a named name. So I try this:

```
var output models.ResponseQueryHotel

var data models.ResponseQueryHotelsData
output.Data.Hotels = append(output.Data.Hotels, data)
```

But I get this error:

```
cannot use data (variable of type models.ResponseQueryHotelsData) as struct{Data models.ResponseQueryHotelsData "json:\"data\""} value in argument to append
```

What should I do to append items to `output.Data.Hotels` (there will be more than 1 `ResponseQueryHotelsData` to append).

And BTW I can't change the structs (it's out of my control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an alias to the identical underlying type if you need to use it multiple times:

```golang
type Hotel = struct {
    Data ResponseQueryHotelsData `json:"data"`
}
hotels := []Hotel{
    {Data: ResponseQueryHotelsData{}},
    {Data: ResponseQueryHotelsData{}},
}

output.Data.Hotels = append(output.Data.Hotels, hotels...)
```

Or declare the struct type in place if you only need it once:

```golang
hotels := []struct {
    Data ResponseQueryHotelsData `json:"data"`
}{
    {Data: ResponseQueryHotelsData{}},
    {Data: ResponseQueryHotelsData{}},
}

output.Data.Hotels = append(output.Data.Hotels, hotels...)
```

The **Assignability** section in [the golang spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) states:

> A value x of type V is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - V and T are identical.
> - **V and T have identical underlying types but are not type parameters and at least one of V or T is not a named type.**
> - V and T are channel types with identical element types, V is a bidirectional channel, and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
> - T is an interface type, but not a type parameter, and x implements T.
> - x is the predeclared identifier nil and T is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type, but not a type parameter.
> - x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.

Answer (score 0):

You can change type of field Data.Hotels to []ResponseQueryHotelsData instead of struct.

Comment: unfortunately, the struct model is not up to me